# Running Custom Docker Image as a step in cloud build

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I've been playing around with cloudbuild and hit a hurdle where I'm not able to run a custom docker image as a step in cloudbuild.

The error message docker:

> " Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./deploy/run-server.sh\": permission denied": unknown. "

- Checked if the image is working locally: Works

The cloudbuild.yaml file looks like:

```
steps:
- name: abcd
  waitFor: ["-"]
  id: "build_image"
- name: 'gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE_NAME}:${COMMIT_SHA}'
  env: ["var=a"]
  waitFor: ['build_image']
```

Run the image just like docker run would work and execute the commands.

Comment: What I'd suggest is trying to run your container image on GCP and see if that shows an error.  For example, create a GCP compute engine based on the image and see if it starts and, if not, what might be logged in Stack Driver.  If not sensitive, you might also want to post the Dockerfile used to create that image.  Does "run-server.sh" mean anything to you by way of a context?

Comment: The image that I'm trying to run in the cloud build already works on GKE, we're in the process of moving from CircleCI to CloudBuild. I'll try starting a GCP instance with container image. "run-server.sh" is the entrypoint for the docker image.